# Running SQL query in pandas

Tags: python, sql, pandas, odbc, pyodbc

I am newbie to SQL query .. I am writing code and querying database in python.. Below is my code and I am not sure about the problem with the code:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
#import datetime
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile
df_lots=pd.DataFrame()

sql = """
DECLARE @carts NVARCHAR(25) = 'Large';
DECLARE @item_type NVARCHAR(50)= 'Produce';
DECLARE @read_point INT= 0;
DECLARE @item_type NVARCHAR(MAX)= N'';
SELECT @item_type+=N',' + [items]
    FROM
        (
            SELECT distinct D.items
                FROM [dbo].[ITEM_SET_COMPACT_VIEW] D
                JOIN [dbo].[Placement] E 
                ON D.items=E.items
                WHERE D.[items] LIKE 'Large'
            ) x
    ORDER BY items;
SET @item_type = STUFF(@item_type, 1, 1, '');
SELECT *
    FROM [dbo].[Get_Data](@item_type, @item_type, @read_point, 1, 0);
"""
try:
    mssql_connection = pyodbc.connect('''
    DRIVER=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;
    SERVER=XXXXXXX;
    DATABASE=XXXXXX;
    UID=XXXXXXXX;
    PWD=XXXXXXXX;
    ''')

    with mssql_connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(sql )
        lots=cursor.fetchall()

except pyodbc.Error as ex:
    print(f"Unexpected error {ex}")
df_lots=pd.DataFrame(np.array(lots))
```

When I run the above code, its giving me following error:

> Unexpected error No results.  Previous SQL was not a query.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-e3e7b4c5dae4> in <module>
     45 except pyodbc.Error as ex:
     46     print(f"Unexpected error {ex}")
---> 47 df_lots=pd.DataFrame(np.array(lots))

NameError: name 'lots' is not defined
```

Can anyone help me overcoming this problem??

Comment: There is a modification in the code:   `DECLARE @items NVARCHAR(50)= 'Produce';`      
`FROM [dbo].[Get_Data](@items, @item_type, @read_point, 1, 0);`

Answer (score 0):

The variable `lots` is created inside the `try ... except` block. When an exception occurs in this block the variable `lots` is not defined, and then the line

`df_lots=pd.DataFrame(np.array(lots))`

results in an error.

Comment: I extracted the data when I ran the same query separately in dbeaver..

Comment: `Unexpected error No results. Previous SQL was not a query.` This is the error I was getting..